# symfony2: how to include line breaks / newlines in translations?

Tags: symfony, internationalization, twig, yaml

how am I supposed to get line breaks working in Symfony 2.4?

```
#messages.de.yml
foo: |
    Hello i am a line
    Hello i am a new line
```

and

```
#messages.de.yml
foo: >
    Hello i am a line
    Hello i am a new line
```

twig

```
#template.html.twig
{{ 'foo'|trans }}
```

The translation is working but line breaks aren't.

The documentation isn't really clear to me. Hints will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Twig does not convert line feeds to `<br />` automatically.

Use the **[nl2br](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/nl2br.html)** filter.

```
#template.html.twig
{{ 'foo'|trans|nl2br }}
```

I'm not quite sure but eventually you'll have to add `\n` to the translation strings additonally.

```
#messages.<locale>.yml
foo: >
    Hello i am a line \n
    Hello i am a new line
```

Comment: "I'm not quite sure but eventually you'll have to add \n to the translation strings additonally." The [`pipe` annotation](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760844) is here for that purpose :)

Comment: The good answer is the Dado's one. You have to use pipe | to have nl2br filter working.

Answer (score 9):

In your YAML file use:

```
foo: |
    first line
    second line
```

and in your TWIG file:

```
<p>{{ 'foo'|trans|nl2br }}</p>
```

tested on:

- Symfony version 2.6.6
- twig/twig 1.x-dev 6792014

Answer (score 2):

For me the following version did the trick:

```
foo: "| Hello \n this is a new line"
```